# Problem with calculating Primes within a given Range in C++

Tags: c++, math

Im trying to create a program that does various math operations, and i wanted to start with calculating prime numbers within a given range. However, when i try to execute the code, it just returns `exit status -1`. What is wrong with the program and how do i fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void getPrimes(int min, int max) {

  int range = max - min;

  std::vector< int > possible_values;

  for (int q = 0; q < range; q++) {

    possible_values.push_back(min + q);

  }

  for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) { 

    int num_of_factors = 0;
    int num = possible_values.at(i);

    for (int c = 0; c < num; c++) {
      if (num % c == 0) {
        num_of_factors++;
      }
    }

    if (num_of_factors == 0) {
      std::cout << num << endl;
    }
  }
}

int main() {

  int min, max;

  std::cout << "min: ";
  std::cin >> min;

  std::cout << "max: ";
  std::cin >> max;

  getPrimes(min, max);
}
```

Comment: `num % c` You're dividing by zero.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `c` is `0` at this expression: `if (num % c == 0) {` ?

Comment: You may find researching segmented prime number sieves to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

this loop should start from 2 because :

1. `c%0` is undefined behavior
2. every number %1 is 0 so you can see why num_of_factors is never 0

   ```
   for (int c = 2; c < num; c++) {
       if (num % c == 0) {
           num_of_factors++;
       }
   }
   ```